# винда ругается на скомпилированный в .exe python файл

Tags: python-3.x

скомпилировал программу на питоне в .exe с помощью pyinstaller. при попытке скачать эту прогу с файлообменника на другой пк винда его блочит без права выбора. архивация так же не помогает.
я новичок в этом деле, поэтому не особо разбираюсь. гугл говорит, что нужны какие-то сертификаты, но я в этом вообще дуб дубом.
буду признателен за любые советы

Comment: Блочит не винда, а антивирусник, скорее всего. pyinstaller - это не компилятор, а упаковщик. Производимые им исполняемые файлы похожи на вирусы.

Answer (score 1):

1. Чтобы передать данный .exe файл на другой компьютер, добавьте его в архив, и установите пароль. В запароленный архив, ваш антивирус не сможет проникнуть.
2. Создайте папку, и добавьте её в исключение антивируса, чтобы любые действия в ней игнорировались антивирусом. А значит и сможете его разархивировать. После деархивации, добавляете .exe файл в белый лист антивируса. Т.е. в доверенное.
3. Сертефикаты - подпись в .exe файлу, которая гарантирует, что файл с момента его создания, до момента запуска не был изменен третьим лицом. Меняете содержимое подписанного файла - хэшсумма перестает совпадать с той, что храниться в сертефикате, а значит файл был модифицирован. Для пользовательских программ это не обязательно.